# Django DetailView pk error: can't match the last one

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

My new to django. I am creating a simple model for my to do app in django. Here, I have used DetailView to get the details and using the int "pk". When I'm running my server the /task/1/ is working fine but when I'm running task/2/ to check the other task it is shwoing error.

My views.py:
[views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1n2x.png)

My app urls.py:
[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmUN2.png)

[template of detailview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpoij.png)

See, when I'm running task/1/ there's no error.

Comment: Please don't upload images of code / errors, [edit] your question and add them as _text_ formatted as code. Please see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: done. thanks, I was not aware of it.

Comment: What is done? I still see you have images of code or errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the query of PK 2 doesn't not exists maybe you have deleted it.

Try number 3 or 4 to check.

Try going to your admin page to find Pk of each row.

Comment: Yes, I had deleted the task and added a new one. I'm new to this so, I couldn't get it that even if the task was deleted the count will not consisdered.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution. As mentioned in the above comment that I might have deleted my task. Yes, that was deleted and even if we delete our task, the new task will not get the pk number that was assigned to the previous one. So, instead, if we'll use pk as the larger number than the previous number we won't get the error.